# How to solve: xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations?

Tags: flutter, dart

I try to run application on macOS, when I try from bottom vscode menu, nothing happens.
Command flutter run -d macos gives me this error:

```
--- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
{ platform:macOS, arch:arm64, id:00006000-000207261E28031E }
{ platform:macOS, arch:x86_64, id:00006000-000207261E28031E }
diff: /Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.
** BUILD FAILED **
```

I'm looking for solution letting me to fix this. Thank you

I try to run application on macOS, when I try from bottom vscode menu, nothing happens.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was:

```
cd macos
pod install
```